# Regex string match uuid beetwin the words

Tags: java, regex

How to write regex that will be matches to this string

Received request with messageId:test, clientId:7da6554c-e3ed-49ed-9a7f-f810f98ceb7f has been processed

uuid will be always different

so i want to check some big text and if it contains

Received request with messageId:test, clientId:*some uuid* has been processed

```
bigText.matches(regex) == true
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: a lot of regex and still stuck on it

Comment: Do you have to do this with a single regular expression?  What’s wrong with `if (line.startsWith("Received request with messageId:test, clientId:"))`?

Comment: it is a log with huge text, so it does not work in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match the specified string pattern

```
Received request with messageId:test, clientId:[\\w-]+ has been processed
```

Full code for Java language :

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Your larger text
        String largerText = "Received request with messageId:test, clientId:7da6554c-e3ed-49ed-9a7f-f810f98ceb7f has been processed";

        // Define the regular expression pattern
        String pattern = "Received request with messageId:test, clientId:[\\w-]+ has been processed";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Create a Matcher object
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(largerText);

        // Check if a match was found
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String matchedText = matcher.group();
            System.out.println("Match found: " + matchedText);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No match found");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Match found: Received request with messageId:test, clientId:7da6554c-e3ed-49ed-9a7f-f810f98ceb7f has been processed
```

**Explanation:**

**pattern :** is the regular expression pattern that looks for the fixed part "Received request with messageId:test, clientId:" followed by one or more word characters (\w) and hyphens (-) for the UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regular expressions, I would just look for the message prefix.

```
String message = "Some other text here.  Received request with messageId:test, clientId:7da6554c-e3ed-49ed-9a7f-f810f98ceb7f has been processed";

System.out.println(checkRequest(message) ? "Received" : "Unknown request");
         
        
static String MESSAGE_PREFIX = "Received request with messageId:test, clientId:";
public static boolean checkRequest(String text) {
    return text.indexOf(MESSAGE_PREFIX) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem of this solution that it only works with Received request with messageId:test, clientId:7da6554c-e3ed-49ed-9a7f-f810f98ceb7f has been processed, if the message will be like this at the end -has been failed - your prefix checker will be ruin the app

Comment: I see.  But your question didn't provide sufficient details to know that.  You wanted to check for a particular string apparently in isolation and did not specify other constraints which might lead to a more optimal solution.